# Which document class/package produced this document?

Tags: document-classes

I'm very curious as to what document class could produce a document like this. I'd like to use it myself but I don't have access to the TeX source. Has anyone seen something similar (or the same)? And is there some central gallery for TeX document classes?

[image]

Comment: Have you looked into the PDF metadata? Often, there's some information about the class in the, e.g. in case of KOMA-Script or `cvmodern`.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

'Inverse' questions like this are very tricky :) It could have been produced using any number of documentclass However, if I had to bet, my money would go on the [exam documentclass](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/exam) which provides many useful features for typesetting exams- the only one I have used in the MWE is the `questions` environment, but there is a lot more you can do with it (see the documentation for details).

[image: exam screenshot]

I've used the `mdframed` package for the framing, but it might have been done using an `\fbox`

```
\documentclass[11pt]{exam}
\usepackage{mdframed}

\setlength{\parindent}{0mm}
\begin{document}
\begin{mdframed}
 {\bfseries Math 114E}

{\itshape Practice Midterm 2 Solutions \hfill March 18, 2012}
\end{mdframed}

\begin{questions}
\question The equation of the sphere is $(x-3)^2+y^2+(z+4)^2=25$. To 
find a place, we need a normal vector and a point on the plane. To find the 
normal, we take the gradient of our surface to get
\[
\vec{u}=(2(x-3),2y,2(z+4))=(8,6,0)
\]
So (dividing by $2$) our normal vector is $\vec{u}=(4,3,0)$, and our point
is $(7,3,-4)$, so we are all set.
\end{questions}
\end{document}
```

The same effect could easily have been created using the `article` `documentclass` as well. This does not have a `question` environment built-in though, so I created one based on the `enumerate` environment, using the `enumitem` to do the heavy lifting for me.

[image: article]

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{mdframed}

\usepackage{enumitem}
\newlist{questions}{enumerate}{5}
\setlist[questions]{label*=\arabic*.}

\setlength{\parindent}{0mm}
\begin{document}
\begin{mdframed}
 {\bfseries Math 114E}

{\itshape Practice Midterm 2 Solutions \hfill March 18, 2012}
\end{mdframed}

\begin{questions}
\item The equation of the sphere is $(x-3)^2+y^2+(z+4)^2=25$. To 
find a place, we need a normal vector and a point on the plane. To find the 
normal, we take the gradient of our surface to get
\[
\vec{u}=(2(x-3),2y,2(z+4))=(8,6,0)
\]
So (dividing by $2$) our normal vector is $\vec{u}=(4,3,0)$, and our point
is $(7,3,-4)$, so we are all set.
\end{questions}
\end{document}
```

In both cases, tweaks to the page geometry could be achieved using the `geometry` package.